# What are some animation techniques that help lower animation cost as much as possible?

Tags: animation, budget

I think this is a good example, but there's no animation to speak, but I am wondering if there are other animation techniques that can yield similar cost per minutes as the "animation" in the video. I am thinking of doing a music video that's cheaply animated.

Answer (score 1):

The most common shortcut I know of is to animate “on twos” which basically means to show each frame twice.  So if the video standard calls for 24 frames per second, the animation will only consist of 12 unique frames, effectively cutting the cost per unit of runtime in half.  Since the technique cultivated a wide viewership with hand-drawn animation, it is also used on computer animated shows which seek to reduce the costs of render time.  Combining this technique with motion “tweening” can further reduce the associated costs.  Tweening software (Twixtor, e.g.)  calculates intermittent frames synthetically, usually through optical flow analysis of pixel motion, but increasingly also through machine learning techniques.